# NoMethodError in Human_resources/leaves#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

It was working few days ago, don't know what had went wrong...

```
**undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

Extracted source (around line #26):

23:             %td= number_with_precision(employee.compensation_leave_balance, precision:1)
24:   #calendar.tab-pane.fade
25:     = calendar(:year => 2012, :month => 6, :first_day_of_week => 1, summary: "Leave Calendar", calendar_title: "June", month_header: true) do |date|
26:       - render_leave_calendar_cell(date)
27:   #trash.tab-pane.fade
28:     = render 'table', leaves: @leaves.where(deleted: true)

app/helpers/leaves_helper.rb:11:in `block in events_for'
app/helpers/leaves_helper.rb:10:in `events_for'
app/helpers/leaves_helper.rb:4:in `render_leave_calendar_cell'
app/views/human_resources/leaves/index.html.haml:26:in `block in _app_views_human_resources_leaves_index_html_haml__145883348_88978910'
app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb:146:in `call'
app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb:146:in `block in calendar'
app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb:145:in `upto'
app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb:145:in `calendar'
app/views/human_resources/leaves/index.html.haml:25:in `_app_views_human_resources_leaves_index_html_haml__145883348_88978910'
```

really don't know what went wrong

```
a/h/leaves_helper.rb                                                                                                                        
   1 module LeavesHelper
   2   def render_leave_calendar_cell(date)
   3     html = content_tag(:span, date.day, class: 'dayDisplay')
   4     html += content_tag(:div, events_for(date))
   5     raw(html)
   6   end
   7 
   8   def events_for(date)                                                                                                                  
   9     html = ""
  10     current_company.leaves.where("start_date <= '#{date}' and return_date > '#{date}'").where(deleted: false).each do |leave|
  11       html += content_tag(:div, leave.applicant.name, class: 'leaveName')
  12     end
  13     raw html
  14   end
```

could it be the date nil? how to fix this ><

much appreciate
Billy

Comment: the error is in line 11 of leaves_helper that means the leaves which your query `current_company.leaves.where("start_date <= '#{date}' and return_date > '#{date}'").where(deleted: false)` is returning has one `leave` document where your `applicant` is not present therefore `leave.applicant` is returning nil

Comment: i know but what should i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as abhas already stated, `leave.applicant` is nil for at least one of the leaves.

go to your database and find out which it is. then figure out what to do with your leaves. delete them too, re-add the missing applicant or what ever data migration might be sensible.

a quick fix would be to skip if an applicant is missing:

```
html += content_tag(:div, leave.applicant.name, class: 'leaveName') if leave.applicant.present?
```

i would also have a look if you properly configured the delete cascades in your application. this often causes such problems. if you want to enforce safety in this regard, you should add database constraints, that ensure that no referenced entity gets deleted.